# Why ? - Second level cache should be set to false for batch updates is this true

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping, second-level-cache, hibernate-batch-updates

Hibernate documentation says second level cache should be set to false for batch updates is this true , if so why ? both are true is any problem ? 
org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
true
 50

Comment: How to temporarily disable second level cache ?

Answer (score 2):

The second level cache keeps a reference to all objects which are used in the current transaction. Batch updates are mostly used to update many objects (> 10'000). That many objects need a lot of memory but for little gain: You probably don't need any of them again, soon (or rather, if you update a million objects, you don't really know which one of them you'll need next).

So putting all these objects in the second level cache poses two problems: 1. It wastes memory and 2. it can allocate so much memory that you run out of it.

To disable the cache for the current session, use `session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE)`. Source: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=964775

Comment: Thanks.how to temporarily disable second level cache

Comment: Try `session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE)`. Source: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=964775